# visual c++ program issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. When I am building my application in Debug mode, it is producing an EXE file (like it is supposed to be doing). But then (which is very surprising for me), when I change the mode from Debug to the Release mode, the compiler builds the application as a .DLL file?

I have only very recently started to use Visual Studio 2010, so don't know my way around it yet. How do I fix this so that when it is compiling in Release mode, to build the application as an .exe file ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyz1h6zd.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your project type to Windows Application.

In the IDE, right click on your project, and select Properties.
Configuration Properties->General->Configuration Type set to 'Application (.exe)'

Answer (score 1):

In project options you should be able to choose whether you're building a .DLL or .EXE. I thought these were the same for all configurations, but you can check to see for yourself.

Comment: No, they are not necessarily the same.